# Java, Calculating When Operator Is A Variable

Tags: java

Lets say you have:

```
int number1 = 5;
int number2 = 5;
char operator = '*';
```

How can I use the character for a calculation: `number1 (operator) number2 = 5*5`
Edit: It was my first time posting anything on this site and I am also an amateur, so I guess thats why I got downvoted 8x cus it was unclear but ty for the people who answered. Will be more thorough next time :)

Comment: Try using a `switch/case` statement: `switch (operator) { case '*': ...; case ....}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch or a simple if condition for an example

```js
if(operator == '*'){
int total = number1 * number2;
}else if(operator == '+'){
int total = number + number2;
}
```

Like this you can do the calculations

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch case for your purpose.

if operator is char type than

```
 int result=0;
switch(operator){
        case '+':
            result=number1+number2;

        case '-':
            result=number1-number2;

        case '*':
            result=number1*number2;

        case '/':
            result=number1/number2;
}
```